# add values in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
def get_quantities(orders):
    """  (dict of {str: list of str}) -> dict of {str: int}

    >>> get_quantities({'t1': ['Vegetarian stew', 'Poutine', 'Vegetarian stew'], 
                        't3': ['Steak pie', 'Poutine', 'Vegetarian stew'], 
                        't4': ['Steak pie', 'Steak pie']})
    {'Vegetarian stew': 3, 'Poutine': 2, 'Steak pie': 3}    
    """
    food_quantity = {}
    total = 0

    for table in orders:
        for food in orders[table]:
            food_quantity[food] += 1

    return food_quantity
```

I seem to get a key error when I try add the values inside the dictionary, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`food_quantity[food]` doesn't exist yet to add `1` to. If it doesn't exist, you *probably* want to add `1` to `0`, but Python doesn't assume that.

`defaultdict` to the rescue!

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> food_quantity = defaultdict(int)
>>> food_quantity[food] += 1
>>> food_quantity[food]
1
```

the `defaultdict(int)` creates a new int (value `0`) in place of `KeyError`s. This works for lookups and augmented assignments (`+=`)

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

> Returns a new dictionary-like object. defaultdict is a subclass of the built-in dict class. It overrides one method and adds one writable instance variable. The remaining functionality is the same as for the dict class and is not documented here.
>
> The first argument provides the initial value for the default_factory attribute; it defaults to None. All remaining arguments are treated the same as if they were passed to the dict constructor, including keyword arguments.